# JQuery getJSON CORS error even though not making Cross Origin Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, raspberry-pi, cors

I have my [website](http://dvc-raspberrypi.ucsd.edu/) deployed on a Pi on my school server. The JS contains calls that make a GET request to the same domain. (It runs Flask). Why is this considered a cross origin request when I'm not trying to hit a different domain?

My js scripts are in a directory other than the document root. You can also inspect the elements in the browser directly.

```
.
├── configs.js
├── index.html
├── logs.html
├── node_modules
│   └── all my libraries
├── README.md
└── resources
    ├── css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── images
    │   └── dvc.png
    └── js
        ├── log-chart.js
        └── script.js

41 directories, 472 files
```

Comment: Is it the same port and server? Those also compose an origin.

Comment: The flask REST call is done through `http://dvc-raspberrypi.ucsd.edu:5000/door`. The school assigned my Pi the following: 

    IP=132.239.214.30
    Hostname=dvc-raspberrypi.ucsd.edu
    Gateway=132.239.214.1
    Net Mask=255.255.255.192

I'm guessing it may be a different port?

Comment: Would this be easier than setting up mod_wsgi and deploying it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port numbers are considered part of the domain when testing cross-origin requests, so it has to be going to the same port as the requesting page. Your website is `http://dvc-raspberrypi.ucsd.edu/`, but you're trying to access `http://dvc-raspberrypi.ucsd.edu:5000/door`. Port 5000 makes them different origins.

Comment: I will try setting the port to 80 then.

Comment: Wait...my front end is running on Apache using port 80. How can I have my backend use port 80? Ideally I'd like to be able to make calls like so:
`http:dvc-raspberrypi.ucsd.edu/door`. But that would be ambiguous with a file in the front-end document root. I suppose I could put the back and front end in the same directory, but I'd like to keep them separate.

Comment: You can do it with different ports, but then you need to implement CORS to allow it.

Comment: So it seems I have a few options. 1. Implement CORS and keep the front and back end on different ports. 2. Have Flask serve the web pages (same directory). I have also been thinking about switching to node.js, which would be the same as option 2, I suppose. What would you recommend?

Comment: I have no recommendation. I don't know what your constraints are. I don't know anything about Flask.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll have to think on this before I make a decision then. Thanks for the help!