# $.getJSON not working within the Amazon Mechanical Turk environment.

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, getjson

For those who don't know Amazon Mechanical Turk:

> Amazon Mechanical Turk (MTurk) is a crowdsourcing Internet marketplace
>   enabling individuals and businesses (known as Requesters) to
>   coordinate the use of human intelligence to perform tasks that
>   computers are currently unable to do. It is one of the sites of Amazon
>   Web Services.

This makes it an ideal place to conduct certain psychological experiments, which is why I am using it.

I've got a server running, on which I'm hosting my 'experiment' (read:website). It's still in development, but most of the functionality is there

In the experiment, I use JS to requests data from Python Flask running on the server via the following code:

```
$.getJSON('https://annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl:80/get_trial', function(data) {
        data_holder = data
        trials = {}
        for(count=0;count < data_holder['trials'].length;count++)
        {
            trials[count] = {'meta':{}}
            trials[count]['meta'] = {'url':data_holder['trials'][count][0]}
        }
    });
```

When directly visiting my .html trough a browser, this works as intended and I receive my data. It also works when previewing the HIT, just before publishing it. When it is published to Amazon however, it stops functioning.

My webpage with all code: https://annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl/experiment/ The code refereed to in the question is in js/communicator.js

My question: How can i enable the functionality of getJSON in Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Comment: My first guess would be problems with CORS. "Stops functioning" - any error messages in the console?

Comment: None. Just an error that `trials` isn't defined, which would've been defined if the getJSON worked. Also no output from the serverside.

Comment: Since JSON URL has port (`80`) and the source web page's URL does not, the request is considered as **cross-domain**. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) for details. So don't specify port in JSON URL if you don't want have problems with CORS.

Comment: Hmm, so Amazon does not have port 80, and as a result it's cross-domain when getJSON tries to reach the data on my server via port 80? 

Is there a way to see what port Amazon does have?

Comment: You could enable CORS for the amazon domains on your server: https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: _Is there a way to see what port Amazon does have?_ It doesn't matter what port does Amazon have. If you don't want deal with CORS you **should not** specify port in the request's URL unless the source web page's URL has the same port.

Comment: I'm hosting my website with Apache on 443 however. Can i also run the Flask on the same port? If not, I'd be forced to use CORS, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery getJSON CORS error even though not making Cross Origin Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501496/jquery-getjson-cors-error-even-though-not-making-cross-origin-request)